# iPhone slider volume controller to another controller

Tags: iphone, sdk, slider

I'm new in objective-c, I created a `firstcontroller` which play a song:
`[mysong play]` also create a slider control of volume:
`mysong.volume=slider.value`

It works fine, and I create another view controller `remoteController` with a play button and slider to control `firstcontroller` to play the song, I can play the song but how can 
I pass the slider value to control the volume, thank you someone can enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clearly explained but I'd say you can add a property to your `FirstController` class that exposes the volume value. Something like this:

```
@interface FirstController : ...
{
    float _level;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) float volumeLevel;
@end

@implementation FirstController
@synthesize volumeLevel = _level;

- (id)init {
    ...
    _level = -1;
    ...
}

- (void)setVolumeLevel:(float)level {
    _level = level;
    <# update slider volume here #>
}

- (float)volumeLevel {
    if (_level < 0) {
       /* first access */
        _level = <# read the volume from the slider #>
    } 
    return _level;
}
@end
```

If you show us some actual code we can taylor the answer to your needs.